# Is there a reverse "fstring"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, f-string

I need to find a way to call a way to use something with fstring syntax to retrieve information from a string.

My goal is to use the same fstring to create a string, and then decode it.

For example:

```py
def encode():
    a = "fizz"
    b = "buzz"
    return f"{a} / {b}"

def decode(my_string: str):
    a = ""
    b = ""
    f"{a} / {b}" # Something like that, more or less.
    print(a) # fizz
    print(b) # buzz
```

I know this example is stupid, but I really need something like that. I work with a proprietary testing software that allow me to call python script, but these scripts can only return values to the software by writing to stdout. And, then, I want to retrieve them in another script called further.

---

I know there is a possibility to retrieve it with regex, but I want to have the same "fstring" for both functions, to avoid duplication.

Comment: From the output of `encode` you have no information about which parts of the string were formatted to begin with. If you had the _template_ (`"{a} / {b}"`), which was then used with `str.format`, you might have more success.

Comment: Yes if you have a template then you would use [python-parse](https://pypi.org/project/parse/).

Comment: @wim that's a very handy library, although I'd have been tempted to call it `gstring`...

Comment: A general approach is impossible, because `a` and `b` might contain the substring `" / "` themselves so the result would be ambiguous. There are several approaches for this specific case where `a` and `b` are more constrained, such as `split` and `re`.

Comment: Formatting and parsing are so different, that "having the same fstring to avoid duplication" does not give any advantage.

Comment: Sounds like possible [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). *Why* exactly do you "really need something like that"? Regardless, I would say "no" because there is a loss of information involved.

Answer (score 1):

```
def encode():
    a = "fizz"
    b = "buzz"
    return f"{a}/{b}"

def decode(my_string: str,d="/"):
    a,b = my_string.split(d)
    print(a) # fizz
    print(b) # buzz
```

Answer (score 1):

To a certain degree this is possible if you can make restrictions to your arguments `a` and `b` and your string. E.g. if your string always has the form `f"{a} / {b}"` and no `" / "` appears in `a` or `b` you can use that information:

```py
def encode(a, b):
    return f"{a} / {b}"

def decode(my_str: str):
    return my_str.split(" / ")


a = "fizz"
b = "buzz"

my_str = encode(a, b)
dec_a, dec_b = decode(my_str)
print(dec_a, dec_b)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should split using your delimiter, in this case it was "/".
So do the following:

```
def decode(myString: str, delimiter="/"):
    a,b = muString.split(delimiter)
    print(f"{a}/{b}")
```

Comment: The main drawback of your answer is that if I change the parameters order in "encode" function, then I need to change them in "decode" too.

Answer (score 0):

You can, to some extent, turn it on its head and have a "reverse regular expression". It works by parsing the regular expression with another regular expression (yikes!):

```
import re

pattern = r'(?P<a>.*?) / (?P<b>.*?)'

def format_re(regexp, **kwargs):
    def replace_fn(match):
        return kwargs[match.group('group_name')]
    return re.sub(
        r'\(\?P<(?P<group_name>.*?)>.*?\)',
        replace_fn,
        pattern)

def encode(a, b):
    return format_re(pattern, a=a, b=b)

def decode(my_string):
    match = re.match('^' + pattern + '$', my_string)
    return match.group('a'), match.group('b')

print(encode('fizz', 'buzz')) # fizz / buzz
print(decode('fizz / buzz'))  # ('fizz', 'buzz')
```

Of course, unnamed, nested and repeated groups will cause trouble, and so will regex metacharacters outside capture groups. And I'm sure there are other problems with it that I don't care to think about right now.

I don't think all this overhead is better than the very slight amount of duplication, but there you have it.

Comment: I mentioned regex in my question. I don't want to use it.

Comment: I thought your goal was to eliminate duplication. The short answer to your question is "no".